# OpenSSL Node certificate path

Tags: node.js, openssl, certificate

I obtained a signed SSL certificate wich resulted on 3 .cer files, that form the certificate path:

cer1
    cer2
        cer3

I then imported the the child certificate (cer3) to IIS and then associated it to my site, without any problems. When I access the site I don't get any errors informinf that the certificate isn't of trust.

Now my application uses node. Therefore, since those requests are through Javascript I added the .cer files to node's cert folder.

Since I need the private key I followed the steps described here:

http://nl.globalsign.com/en/support/ssl+certificates/microsoft/all+windows+servers/export+private+key+or+certificate/

I had no trouble generating the private key (.key) file and copied it also to the the cert folder (along with the 3 .cer files.

Unfortunatelly this didn't work because when I make submit a form that consequently makes a request to node, the browser throws and execption informing that there are problems with the certificate.

Are OpenSSL's comands different since there is a certificate path on this case?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue simply adding a reference to the certification authority (ca line):

```
var options = { 
  key: fs.readFileSync("keys/cer1.key"), 
  cert: fs.readFileSync("certs/cer2.crt"), 
  ca: fs.readFileSync("ca/ca.crt") 
}; 

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) { 
  ... 
}).listen(8000);
```

Thanks